# C code using double struct hack (flexible array member) in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to test Github code and it has struct hack technique which is like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int wcount;
    double weights[];
}Node;

typedef struct Layer {
    int ncount;
    Node nodes[];
}Layer;

void main()
{
    Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(n));
}
```

But when I try to compile and run this code in "Visual Studio C++", it gives me error on line 11:

```
 11:   Node nodes[];
```

but this code works in Linux system which compiles with gcc, and for sure has no grammar mistake.
I want to know why it does not work and what should I do to be able to use it in Visual Studio.

Comment: "for sure I have no grammar mistake" - that depends on what standard you are working to... You are using flexible array members which are non standard. Try compiling with `--pedantic` on linux

Comment: @John3136 I'm pretty sure that flexible array members are standard in C99 and newer. However, VS compiler does not give a dead rat's tail about these pesky "standards", so they do their own thing.

Comment: this code works fine in linux, gcc or intel compiler  both works...
but as I want to use in visual studio C++, 
it do not let me compile because of that line 11...
is there any trick that I could run this with visual studio C++

Comment: Flexible array members aren't a hack. Using zero-sized array instead is a hack, and it's probably going to work with bot VS and gcc (i.e. `Node nodes[0];`).

Comment: Wait, are you using it in C++? Because you tagged your question `[c]`.

Comment: no it's all about C

Comment: Try the hack from my comment then.

Comment: its strange because if I change Node datatype to double in Layer struct, it works fine.

Comment: Note that you are not supposed to be able to embed structures with a FAM inside any other structure or union.  Pointers are OK; actual structures, or a FAM of a structure with a FAM are not allowed by standard C.  There are sound reasons for the prohibition — there isn't much excuse for GCC permitting the nested structures with FAM.

Comment: changing to Node nodes[0]; do not works too...

Comment: Dimension 0 is not allowed in standard C; again, GCC allows it as an extension.

Comment: as you  mentioned, looks like structure embed another struck that has "struct hack" is not working in "visual studio C++"

Comment: too bad that Visual studio only support standard C, 
since Im unfamilial with gcc and gdb, I think I have to change code to pointers instead of 0-size-array...
thanks for the reply.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers, ¶3 _A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
element of an array._

Comment: I think the real issue is you are trying to create an array of a type that doesn't have fixed size (irrespective if it inside another struct or not). Say you do `layer.nodes[1]` How is the offset supposed to be calculated?

Comment: Ok: "it gives me error on line 11:" is **not** a proper problem description. What you need to include in your question is **what** error do you get. i.e. a verbatim copy of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the "struct hack", which is an old, obsolete method of writing something like `int array[1];` at the end of a struct - which was perfectly unsafe, non-portable and undefined behavior.

During the 1990s, GCC implemented a non-standard extension to solve this, by declaring a zero-length array at the end of the struct. This is also an obsolete technique.

In the year 1999, the problem was finally permanently fixed when the C standard introduced something called *flexible array member*. They are well-defined and have the syntax `type array[];`.

You must allocate room for them like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  ...; // various data
  int array[]; // flexible array member
}

type_t var = malloc( sizeof(var) + sizeof(int[n]) );
```

Everything else but the above is either dirty hacks or non-standard C, and therefore shouldn't be used.

---

The reason why your code doesn't work might be because you don't allocate room for the struct + flexible array member in the same malloc call.

In addition, VS in C mode is hopelessly outdated. They still struggle to implement all C language features from the year 1999. Depending on your VS version, it might not fully support the C language. In the year 2017, I wouldn't recommend to use such old, pre-C99 compilers, when there are modern ones available for free.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer doesn't help, as he isn't using gcc, or a standards compliant compiler.  Just saying "use a different compiler" might not be an option.  Writing code that DOES work on the compiler he DOES use, might be the only option.

Comment: @Neil Apparently some version of VS finally supports flexible array members:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fae073.aspx. Microsoft are simply so outdated in their C knowledge that they label it "a Microsoft extension". Apparently you need Visual Studio 2015 update 3 or later to run C code from the year 1999. Feel free to laugh or cry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using MSVC2015+ and this structure is not a part of a public API you could go with clang frontend with MS backend. I've been using it myself for 2+ years in a Linux/Windows project, this saved me a lot of pain.

Not related to the question but still, do not cast malloc return value in C it is only needed if you intend to compile with C++ compiler.

---

Missed a crucial part:
You can not have a flexible struct member in a flexible struct since it's size is unknown to a compiler. So basically while Node definition is fine Layer will fail. Any given structure may contain only one flexible member and only as the last one, this kind of definition means that after the structure goes an arbitrary amount of elements of a flexible member. It is a developers responsibility to allocate enough memory and to track the amount of the members.

So the code above could be rewritten about this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WEIGHTS 16

typedef struct Node {
  int wcount;
  double weights[];
} Node;

typedef struct Layer {
  int ncount;
  Node *nodes;
} Layer;

void main() {
  Node* n = malloc(sizeof(Node) + MAX_WEIGHTS * sizeof(double));
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(n));
  free(n);
}
```

Obviously you may substitute MAX_WEIGHTS with some runtime value.

---

Elaborating a bit on flexible array members:

```c
typedef struct {
  int a;
  double b[];
} A;

typedef struct {
  float c;
  A a;
} B;

typedef struct {
  float c;
  A as[];
} C;

typedef struct {
  float d;
  A;
} D;

int main() {
  A as[12];
  (void)as;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with clang3.9 and the following flags:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -fms-extensions -Wno-microsoft-anon-tag -Werror
```

```
test.c:8:5: error: 'a' may not be nested in a struct due to flexible array member [-Werror,-Wflexible-array-extensions]
  A a;
    ^
test.c:13:7: error: 'A' may not be used as an array element due to flexible array member [-Werror,-Wflexible-array-extensions]
  A as[];
      ^
test.c:22:7: error: 'A' may not be used as an array element due to flexible array member [-Werror,-Wflexible-array-extensions]
  A as[12];
      ^
```

I do find the first error to be a bit weird, since from the memory layout point of view B and D should be the same. However D is a Microsoft language extension and should not be used in a portable code.

Comment: Correction: "You can not have a flexible struct member in a flexible struct since it's size is unknown to **very old and completely outdated** compilers"

Comment: @Lundin Agrred i've formulated this statement wrongly. The problem is that flexible array member has no size and just hints the compiler that it's content goes straight after the struct. Hence if we have an array of structs with a flexible array members there is no way for compiler to calculate an offset to address this array members.

Comment: The reason you don't get the error with D that you do with B (your comment "I do find the first error to be a bit weird") is because on line 18 you just have `A;` on its own.  Correcting it to `A a;` gives `test.c:18:5: error: 'a' may not be nested in a struct due to flexible array member`

Answer (score -2):

An unsized array inside a struct is non-standard.  Up to VS 6, one could use the MS non-standard `type item[0];` syntax, but they dropped that one later.

The correct syntax is `Node nodes[1];`.

Comment: And how should this work in the end? The size of `Node` is unknown as it also contains `weight[]` with unknown length.

Comment: As stated above, the size is known. The array size is sizeof (Node), isn't it?

Comment: What is `sizeof(Node)` without a fixed size of the `weights[]` array? Even if it is changed to `weights[1]` it would compile but also break the "flexible array" approach completely.

Comment: Even using the correct syntax for both structures, to get the code to compile, this would work as dangerously as it does in gcc, now, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. Therefore I think it isn't a valid answer to fix array length. Then the proper answer should be something like"It does not work this way", shouldn't it?

Comment: It doesn't work this way under gcc as well.  Even tough 'it compiles and there is no (sic) grammar mistake".

Comment: This code would invoke undefined behavior. There might be padding at the end of the struct and if you overwrite padding bits there is no telling what will happen. There is absolutely no reason to write crappy, outdated 1990s programming tricks like this in the year 2017. Just use standard C flexible array members, as the OP already does. You just need to use them correctly, is all.

Comment: The original code is already a gimmick and would obviously involve undefined behaviour, if anyone tried to put data into nodes[] or weigths[]. It is not intended to be run, even though it compiles on gcc, which is a bit worrying in and of itself.

Answer (score -3):

As C is a simple language, you are going to have to do the complicated bits manually.  Keeping track of how many weight items are in a Node and allocating the correct number of bytes is now YOUR problem.

How about something like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int wcount;
    double *weights;
}Node;


void main()
{
    int wcount = 10;
    Node* n = (Node*)malloc(offsetof(Node, Weights) + sizeof(double)* wcount);
    n->Weights[8] = 123; 
}
```

The calculation will work out how many bytes are required up to the start of the weights field, and then just multiply up how many weights are required, giving the total amount.  then you can just use the pointer as if it was an array of the correct number.

Comment: This code invokes undefined behavior. You can't access a `double*` is if it was a `double`. They are not compatible types, there might be alignment issues and so on. There is absolutely no reason to write crappy, outdated 1990s programming tricks like this in the year 2017. Just use standard C flexible array members, as the OP already does. You just need to use them correctly, is all.

Comment: He was always going to access the double as an array, so would need to dereference it somehow.  How does he fix this problem without changing compilers?